# APT says 'package has no installation candidate' althought it shows it in apt list

Tags: php, linux, zeromq, apt

I am trying to install **ZeroMQ extension for PHP** using Docker image `php:7.4-apache-buster`.

The package is found when running `apt list`:

`$ sudo apt update && apt list php-zmq` outputs `php-zmq/stable 1.1.3-9 amd64`

It is not possible to install it however:

`$ sudo apt install php-zmq` outputs `E: Package 'php-zmq' has no installation candidate`

I have checked that the package is not already installed using `apt list --installed php-zmq`. Underlying `libzmq5` library is present on the system.

I wonder how does `apt list` command work that it suggests packages which `apt install` is unable to install.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I was finally able to install the extension using `phpize` (following instructions at https://eole-io.github.io/sandstone-doc/install-zmq-php-linux#installing-the-php-binding) and `docker-php-ext-enable`. However I still wonder why the first solution with `apt` did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The package [`php-zmq`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php/php-zmq) is available in debian main repository , you need to edit your sources as follows:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

**Edit**

Manual install:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-defaults/php-common_69_all.deb
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-zmq/php-zmq_1.1.3-9_amd64.deb
sudo gdebi php-common_69_all.deb
sudo gdebi php-zmq_1.1.3-9_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these repositories are already present in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, as they are by default in Debian Buster.

Comment: This error shows during manual install: `Dependency is not satisfiable: php-common (>= 1:7.0+33~)`. I think `php-common` dependency is really the problem, as it is not installable even separately using `apt install php-common` (`has no installation candidate` error shows).

Comment: @user14967413 This is strange.